# Getting choppy movement using time-based movement

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, createjs

I am using time based movement, but its still super choppy. this code shoots in arrow in the air then calculates the difference in movement to determine to rotation of the arrow. It works most of the time, but sometimes it just jitters.

```
for(i=0;i<this.arrows.length;i++){
        a = this.arrows[i];
        point0 = [a.x,a.y];
        x_speed = e.delta/1000*a.speed * Math.cos(a.angle * Math.PI / 180); 
        y_speed = e.delta/1000*a.speed * Math.sin(a.angle * Math.PI / 180);
        a.x += x_speed;
        a.y += y_speed;
        a.y += a.velocity;
        a.velocity += e.delta/1000*this.gravity;
        alert(e.delta);
        ang = Math.atan2(point0[1]-a.y,point0[0]-a.x);
        ang = (ang  * (180/Math.PI))+180;
        a.rotation = ang;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) I'm surprised you are using a.angle, ang and a.rotation. I guess ang is a var declared before the for loop, but isn't there an issue here ?

2) You might use radians, not degrees, to avoid conversions.

3) There's also an issue with speed vs velocity : you don't update speed (linear speed) when you change velocity (speed on Y).

•• Anyway there's a simpler way of proceeding : compute speed/position just like for a regular point moving, then use the speed vector to compute where the end of the arrow is.

It works fine in this fiddle : http://jsbin.com/dexaroriwixo/1/

update :

```
 var i=0, a=null, delta_ms = 1e-3 * e.delta;
 for(i=0;i<this.arrows.length;i++){
        a = this.arrows[i];
        a.x += delta_ms*a.speedX; 
        a.y += delta_ms*a.speedY;
        a.speedY += delta_ms*this.gravity;
        a.speedNorm = Math.sqrt(sq(a.speedX)+sq(a.speedY));
}
```

to draw :

```
Arrow.prototype.draw = function(ctx) {
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
   ctx.lineTo(this.x+ this.length*this.speedX/this.speedNorm, 
               this.y+ this.length*this.speedY/this.speedNorm );
   ctx.strokeStyle = '#F00';
   ctx.stroke();
}
```

to 'launch' an arrow,

```
 Arrow.prototype.launch(initialSpeed, angle) {
     this.speedX = initialSpeed * Math.cos(angle);
     this.speedY = initialSpeed * Math.sin(angle);
 }
```